# AWS ECS service not starting Task is stuck on Pending

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run a service inside my ECS Cluster . I have defined the task with 4GB of RAM, and 2vCPU. For the container I set 1 vCPU and 2GB as limit. After that I defined a service and linked the task. The service start but the task inside remain stuck in `Provisioning` state.In the container Tab of the task not appear the container.

My task definition:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-3:1234567:task-definition/Task:9",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "my_image_test",
            "image": "1234567.dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/my_image:latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memoryReservation": 2048,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "ingestion-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION",
                    "value": "eu-west-3"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-3",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "Service Task",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 9,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "2048",
    "memory": "4096",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2024-02-09T11:32:31.879Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:user/my_user",
    "tags": []
}
```

I tryed to reduce the memory of the container without any success.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the app? Like the port the application listens on inside the container, the healthcheck endpoint.

Comment: The app listens to the SQS queue applies some elaboration and then stores results in an S3 bucket. I don't have any health check endpoint

Comment: Now works. The problem was related to task CPU and Memory allocation. I use the EC2 Instance for Task execution the resource allocations are only related to Fargate